# Dynamic method name

Tags: php, oop, object

First of all sorry for the title, but i had no clue how i should name it.

Let's say i have it like that:

```
$lang = new lang;
$lang->setLanguage('en');
$string = $lang->get('Willkommen');
```

This would output **Welcome** for example.

But what i want is this:

```
$lang = new lang;
$lang->setLanguage->en
$string = $lang->get->Willkommen
```

As you thought, this should also output **Welcome**.

In order words, i want the same result, but without having to pass arguments to the instance.

I searched a long time now, but could not find out how i could do that.

Comment: Using a method is the simplest solution. The other solution will be much more complicated and, as far as I can see, will cause more problems than it solves.

Comment: Unfortunately i need to do it like that. I need it for the twig template system ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for the [__get magic method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get).

```
class lang {
    var $language = 'en';

    function __get($prop) {
        if ($prop == 'Willkommen') {
            if ($this->language == 'en') return 'Welcome';
            else if ($this->language == 'fr') return 'Bonjour';
        }
    }

    function __set($prop, $val) {
        if ($prop == 'language') $this->language = $val;
    }
}

$lang = new lang();
echo $lang->Willkommen; // Prints "Welcome"
$lang->language = 'fr';
echo $lang->Willkommen; // Prints "Bonjour"
```

Comment: Would it be possible to have it like `$lang->get->Willkommen`? Since i have also a "set" method which gets called to set the desired language. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but i fell a bit confused. What is that `$lang->Willkommen = 'Welcome';`? I guess you missunderstood me. The setLanguage should be to set the language that i want to receive. For example if i set it to "en" i want to receive the enflish string from "Willkommen" which is "Welcome".

Comment: @Michael Edited again in light of what you just told me. Is this what you were looking for? By the way, setting the language like `$lang->setLanguage->en` isn't something that's possible.

Comment: Yeah exactly ^^ Thanks i will try it out. Give me some mins :)

Comment: Thank you so much. Works perfectly. :) *give that man a cookie* :D

Answer (score 1):

In php, dynamic access is with `{}` :

```
$key = 'Willkommen';
$lang->{$key};
```

Comment: Sorry could you please explain this a bit more? How would i handle this in the method? PS: i edited my post to make it clearer.

Comment: did not understand it like that, sry